# Number of ways to distribute 13 (out of 52) cards to 4 indistinguishable players.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Typically, I would approach this problem using combinatorics, which would ask the number of ways to distribute to 1st player, 2, 3rd, 4th, giving
$$
\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}\binom{26}{13}
$$

but I want to understand the permutations approach, which is
$$
\frac{52!}{13!13!13!13!}
$$
This is equivalent to the above, but I am wondering what is the name of this formula for the permutations approach?

It looks like the formula for permutations with duplications. If that's the case, then what are the duplications here? the 13 cards in each pile?

I understand 13! is the number of permutations in each pile, but I don't understand why dividing by it is correct.

Comment: The $\frac{52!}{13!13!13!13!}$ is commonly denoted as the multinomial coefficient: $52 \choose{13,13,13,13}$. Some [background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem). In general, the multinomial coefficient $n \choose{r_1,...,r_k}$, where $r_1+...+r_k = n$ counts the number of ways to distribute $n$ distinguishable elements into $k$ ordered or labelled sets, within which order does not matter. So as per the answer below, since in your case the players are indistinguishable, you have to divide out the over-enumeration due to the implicit labelling of the sets, and divide by $4!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if the players are indistinguishable, then both answers should be divided by $4!$.

Second, the second approach assumes the following: you shuffle the deck, give the first player the first 13 cards, the second player the next 13 cards, and so on. The duplications are the internal order the cards are given to each player. If you take the same deck and shuffle only the first 13 cards, all players will receive the same cards as before, but you count it as a new deck (there are $52!$ of those). So you divide by these repetitions.

**Example** Suppose you have 4 cards to give to 2 players. Cards are labeled ABCD. The number of ways is $\tfrac{4!}{2!2!}=6$ because

AB|CD = BA|CD = BA | DC = AB |CD (these are the $4=2!2!$ reptitions of the event that player 1 has in the end the cards $A$ and $B$ and player 2 the other two.

If, players are not distinguishable than you have only 3 options, because you have only 3 ways to split the 4 cards into two decks and it doesn't matter which gets which (you can't tell them apart anyway... )

Comment: Wait, why should be divided by $4!$? If the players are distinguishable, wouldn't my result by multiplied by $4!$? This accounts for the number of ways we can permute the 4 piles? So if this is correct and you are also correct, then it seems there would be a factor of $(4!)^2$ difference between distinguishable players and undistinguishable players, which seems wrong.

Comment: The value that I found seems to be for choosing 13 cards for players 1,2,3,4 (in this order). There are 4! such orders.

Comment: What you do is cut the deck to 4 piles with an order within the piles. This order can represent the players. (I get the first pile, you the second and so on). To eliminate order, you must divide by the num of permutations. I suggest you to write all the options in the 4 card example, it will give you a good feeling of the problem.

Comment: Ah I think I agree with you. Is the answer by Anand in https://www.quora.com/In-how-many-ways-can-52-cards-be-distributed-to-four-players-with-13-cards-each#:~:text=I.e%20the%20set%20of%20cards,26c13%C3%971%20%C3%974!&text=13%20cards%20are%20drawn%20from%20a%20deck%20of%2052%20cards      wrong? It seems he's over counting by a factor of 4!.

Comment: The 4! orders to give the same hands to different players is already counted in the original formula, you don't need to add it artificially by multiplying by 4!. You only need to kill it if you don't care who gets what.

Comment: Yes, the "Moreover" part is wrong in his answer. Super easy example: a deck has 2 cards, each of the two players gets one. There are $2!$ to do it. His "Moreover" calculation gives $2!^2$ ways, but here we can write all the options down and see how he overcounts.

Answer (score 2):

You can imagine dealing $13$ cards to each of $4$ players as laying out the $52$ cards in a straight line, with player $1$ getting cards $1$ to $13$, player $2$ getting cards $14$ to $26$, and so on.

So you have $52!$ ways to lay out all the cards. But for each of those arrangements, there are many duplicate arrangements in which cards $1$ to $13$ are the same, but in a different order. Similarly for cards $14$ to $26$, and so on. For each group of $13$, there are $13!$ ways to rearrange them and not change the cards in each player's hands. That's why we see four factors of $13!$ in the denominator.

I am not aware of a specific name for this technique.

Comment: Thank you for that great answer, that is so intuitive!!

Answer (score 0):

If the players are indistinguishable, the following approach can be taken.  For convenience, let f(n, k) denote the number of ways of distributing n cards among k indistinguishable players.  We want to find f(52, 4). Note that in general f(n, 1)=1.

One of the players will receive card x for some specified x. In how many ways can card x be distributed?  There are 12 accompanying cards included with x that will be selected among the 51 remaining cards, so we can include card x in C(51, 12) ways.  Once we distribute these 13 cards including card x to any one of the players, we have 3*13=39 cards to distribute among 3 players. f(52,4) = C(51,12)*f(39,3).

We can now proceed as before to compute f(39,3). For each of the groups of cards including x, let y be come card not included with card x.  In how many ways can card y be distributed?  Card y must be accompanied by 12 of the 38 remaining cards, so f(39,13)= C(38,12)*f(26,2) and f(52,4) = C(51,12)*C(38,12)*f(26, 2).  Proceeding in the same way we get f(26, 2) = C(25, 12)*f(13,1), and f(13,1)=1.

So after all that explanation, we get f(52, 4) = C(51, 12)*C(38, 12)*C(25, 12).